# How to cover catch block in Junit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I'm trying to cover a test class to 100%. However, I'm able to do it up to 90% only as I'm not able to test catch block. Can anyone tell me how can I cover the catch block.

Below is my class to be tested:

```
public class UnsubscribeXmlTransformer {

    public Map<String, Object> process(Map<String, Object> requestMap) {

        String inputStream = requestMap.get(NeoConstants.INPUTSTREAM).toString();

        Smooks smooks;
        try {
            smooks = new Smooks("Unsubscribe-smooks.xml");

            JavaResult javaResult = new JavaResult();


            smooks.filterSource(new StringSource(inputStream), javaResult);


            UnsubscribeDetailsVO unsubscribeDetailsVO = (UnsubscribeDetailsVO) javaResult
                    .getBean("unsubscribeDetailsVO");

            requestMap.put("unsubscribeDetailsVO", unsubscribeDetailsVO);

        } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {        }

        return requestMap;
    }
```

}

And here is my Test class:

```
public class UnsubscribeXmlTransformerTest {
    Map<String, Object> requestMap = null;  

    @Before
    public void prepareRequestMap() {
        requestMap = new HashMap<>();
        String inputStream = "some xml tags";

        requestMap.put(NeoConstants.INPUTSTREAM, inputStream);      
    }


    @Test
    public void processTest() throws Exception {
        UnsubscribeXmlTransformer ref = new UnsubscribeXmlTransformer();
        Map<String, Object> result = ref.process(requestMap);

        Assert.assertNotNull("Result is not null", result);
        Assert.assertFalse("Result is not empty", result.isEmpty());
        Assert.assertTrue("Result contains key named inputStream", result.containsKey(NeoConstants.INPUTSTREAM));
        Assert.assertTrue("Result contains key named unsubscribeDetailsVO", result.containsKey("unsubscribeDetailsVO"));
        Assert.assertTrue("Value with key unsubscribeDetailsVO is an instance of UnsubscribeDetailsVO", result.get("unsubscribeDetailsVO") instanceof UnsubscribeDetailsVO);
    }

    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void processTestForException() {
        UnsubscribeXmlTransformer ref = new UnsubscribeXmlTransformer();

        // how to cover                 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Mockito.spy` on your requestMap, and mock case, when exception should be thrown. Then (as pointed by [jannis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4494577/jannis)) you can use AssertJ's fluent API to verify there's no exception thrown (you are muting it in `catch` clause), e.g

```
@Test
public void process_shouldCatchException() throws Exception{
    UnsubscribeXmlTransformer sut = new UnsubscribeXmlTransformer();
    Map<String, Object> requestMap = Mockito.spy(new HashMap<>());
    when(requestMap.put(eq("unsubscribeDetailsVO"), any()))
        .thenThrow(IOException.class);
    assertThatCode(() -> sut.process(requestMap))
        .doesNotThrowAnyException();
}
```

Comment: The assertion part is missing. I prefer [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) for assertions: `Assertions.assertThatCode(() -> sut.process(requestMap)).doesNotThrowAnyException()`

Comment: Right! I missed this. Thanks. I also prefer AssertJ.

Answer (score 0):

Here when we execute classUnderTest.handleError(clienthttpresponse); it will throw Exception in java class ..inorder to coverage the code in catch block in java class we need to write the below code in try block and Assert.fail() , then instead of right away throwing the error it will go into catch block.

```
try {
            Mockito.when(clienthttpresponse.getBody()).thenReturn(targetStream);
            classUnderTest.handleError(clienthttpresponse);
            fail();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass()+""+e.getMessage());
        }
```